# how can I fix the error

Tags: python, linux, database, sqlite

I'm novice here and I have my code, there is running good before I create my SQL query.
I use sqlite3 as database.

**that's my code :**

**code.py**

```
print """<INPUT  Value="Valider" Type="SUBMIT" >

<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">

   {

   alert('thank you.');

   }

   </script>
   </head>"""

print "</body>"
print "</html>"

conn = sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite')
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row 
c = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)

try:
    c.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
except:
     conn.rollback()

cursor.close()
```

when I execute my code, I have this error :

```
sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of the `sql` definition.

Comment: I corrected that, but it's not the problem.

Comment: Do not edit your question to remove errors that you asked about; this would invalidate any earlier answers.

Comment: @CL. : I just corrected the syntax and the error because I don't have the same error now.

Comment: @Glacius, StackOverflow is a forum for focused, reusable technical questions -- such that other people can learn from the question and its answer. Part of that means that questions should be pre-digested to a point where they ask about only one thing, are deduplicated (to only have one question about each "thing"), do so tersely, and can be answered without back-and-forth; see the "correct" part of http://sscce.org/ for more.

Comment: ...so, if you have so many errors in your program that your question needs to evolve over time, it's not ready to be asked yet -- you aren't just asking about one thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : ok I get it, I just wanted to change the question with the answers, but this is a mistake and I'm sorry, it will not happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the quote at the end of the string.

Also, the INSERT statement wants a list of column names; `my_argv[2]` is not a column name.

Furthermore, `%s` is not a database parameter marker; use `?` instead.

Additionally, `getpass` is a module; you cannot call it.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (application,version,path,os,user,ip) "+
      "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine
c.execute(sql, args)
```

Comment: it doesn't work :                                                 args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass().getuser(), machine
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
localhost.localdomain - - [15/Jul/2014 13:09:33] CGI script exit status 0x100

Answer (score 0):

you forget to keep `"`
it should be like

```
sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (application,version,path,os,user,ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

one more thing,while executing the query insert you need to give values

it should be

```
c.execute(sql,(my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine ))
```

Comment: yes I have tried that : sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc (my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass.getuser(), machine ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass().getuser(), machine                                                                                                                                 c.execute(sql, args)

Comment: and I have this error : args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass().getuser(), machine
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @Glacius what are the names of columns in your info_calc table

Comment: that's my creation of my tables in my database script : c.execute('create table info_calc(id integer primary key autoincrement, version text, path text, os text, user text)')                                                             c.execute('create table info_recup(id integer primary key, nom text, adresse text, departement text, projet text)')

Comment: oh sorry I missed two columns ... I just add but it already doesn't works , c.execute('create table info_calc(id integer primary key autoincrement, application text, version text, path text, os text, user text, ip text)')

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't works, I have also tried this syntax : sql = "INSERT INTO info_calc VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"

args = my_argv[2], my_argv[3], my_argv[4], sys.platform, getpass().getuser(), machine
c.execute(sql, args)   , but it doesn't works again.

Comment: @Glacius: You did not state *how* it doesn't work; without at least the exception message it is not immediately obvious you changed `getpass.getuser()` to `getpass().getuser()` there.